# Sequalize convert column value after fetching from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `Date` column 'creation_time' in my Sequalize model.
When I fetch rows from DB, the result object contains the 'creation_time' column as a Date object. This is the expected behavior.

Now, I want this column to appear as a date string. I tried adding getter and setter methods in which I am explicitly setting Date object to String using `JSON.stringify` but this column comes up as a Date field only. Also, tried attaching `get()` method to column definition but still no change.

My model definition if this helps:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  MyModel.init(
    {
      _id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        field: 'id'
      },
    //   creation_time: DataTypes.DATE,
      creation_time: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        get() {
          return JSON.stringify(this.getDataValue('creation_time'));
        }
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      schema: 'dbo',
      modelName: 'my_model',
      tableName: 'my_model',
      getterMethods: {
        creation_time: function () {
          return JSON.stringify(this.getDataValue('creation_time'));
        }
      },
      setterMethods: {
        creation_time: function () {
          return JSON.stringify(this.getDataValue('creation_time'));
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

Expecting a change in column type when I fetch from DB using the following query:

```
const myModel = await MyModel.findOne({
    raw: true,
    nest: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that converting a Sequilize column type is a good idea if there is such scenario for you then you should have keep the type of column from Date to String.

> Also, tried attaching get() method to column definition but still no
> change.

For above purpose, you don't need any getter or custom method because javascript has builtin `toString()` method for this purpose e.g.

```
const myModel = await MyModel.findOne({
    raw: true,
    nest: true,
});

let date_in_string = myModel.creation_time.toString(); //it will convert it to string notation
console.log(date_in_string);
```

Comment: So, my use-case is that my services expect Date fields to be in string format. Want to handle this logic in one place. Getter and setter are kind of meant for the same use-case but did not work for me.

Comment: Cannot change the column type to retain the integrity of Date column.